Checking a value within a cell range through Regexmatch
I need to check a value within a cell range through Regexmatch.
I used the below formula but the result shows in multiple columns but I need to display the result only on the current column.
Data:
 LTM-1750-9.1   LTM-1500    LTM-1300    LTM-1250    LTM-1160    LTM-1130

Formula =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(regexmatch(JD4:JL4,"LTM-1750*"),"YES","NO"))

Result:
NO  YES NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO 



You may try:
=arrayformula(if(or(regexmatch(JD4:JL4,"LTM-1750*")),"YES","NO"))


Perfect answer... Thank you so much rockinfreakshow....

The recommended method to showcase your sample input data is to create a markdown table. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question in general. Additionally you can also add a screenshot and/or test google sheet which could help us in getting a clear picture on what is expected off...

If I want to check with multiple conditions, what should be the formula as the below one is not working..
=arrayformula(if(or(regexmatch(JO4:JW4,"LTM-1090*")),"YES","NO")regexmatch((JO4:JW4,"GR-800"),"YES","NO"))
Please reply...

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Data :
Row1 : GR-800EX GR-700EX GR-600EX GR-550EX GR-500EX
Row2 : LTM-1750-9.1 LTM-1500-9.1 LTM-1300-8.1 LTM-1250-6.1 LTM-1160-5.1 LTM-1130-5.1 LTM-1080-5.1 LTM-1050-5.1
My concern is that, Row 1 Models are belongs to Tadano Cranes where Row2 belongs to Liebherr Cranes but the capacity is same for different models
Example : GR-800EX capacity is 80Ton also LTM-1080-5.1 capacity is also 80Ton
Since I am checking and models and capacity, in the 80Ton Cells, if anyone of the condition meets, it should display YES
Still you have confusion, I can create a sample sheet for you.

Changing resulting array from horizontal to vertical
Kindly try using TOCOL formula to form the resulting value to vertical
=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(regexmatch(JD4:JL4, "LTM-1750*"), "YES", "NO")))

References:
TOCOL

RegexMatch Results in a Vertical using TRANSPOSE
You may add TRANSPOSE to your formula to switch the result from Rows to Column.
Sample formula
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:F1, "LTM-1750"), "YES", "NO")))


Adjust the Range based on your needs.

Sample Output

Reference:
TRANSPOSE
